# skia is missing xcode project files

Tags: xcode, skia

I downloaded Skia project from git repository. I searched the .`xcodeproj` files but couldn't find them... How will I use the project in Xcode?
I am using mac os x 10.8 with xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try running `./gyp_skia --depth=. -f xcode -Dskia_os=mac` in terminal while in `skia` folder?

Comment: worked. Now there are lots of project files, but which is better to choose for learning?